# Blender 2.8 weird render makes Eevee unusable

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I just downloaded Blender 2.8 beta, opened it and chose Eevee render, clicked render view and look what happens,[image]

Another example with a plane and the cube

[image]

Few times this problem happened with cycles render too, like below
[image]

Now It is not about my graphics driver because I downloaded some really graphics heavy content from Blender 2.8 homepage and they rendered perfectly well with both Eevee and Cycles. So I must have missed something, can anyone help?

Comment: This certainly looks like a GPU issue. Have you tried with CPU rendering?